# How to check out of gerrit and not git origin

Tags: git, gerrit

In our setup we check changes into `Gerrit` and they don't make it into `origin`, which is where we check out from, until they get peer reviewed.

As I am new to the whole Git/Gerrit stuff, after I pushed my changes into Gerrit, I actually went to clean up some local branches and actually deleted the branch I pushed the change from.  So now I no longer have a local copy of my changes but they are in Gerrit.  They are not in Git as they have not been peer reviewed yet.

So I went to restore my local changes by checking a new branch out of Gerrit and not the Git origin.  Our remote config looks as follows

```
>git remote -v
gerrit  ssh://myuser@domain:port/server (fetch)
gerrit  ssh://myuser@domain:port/server (push)
origin  ssh://myuser@domain:port/server.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://myuser@domain:port/server.git (push)
```

I tried

```
>git checkout -b gmaster gerrit/refs/heads/master
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'gerrit/refs/heads/master' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

How do I check out a branch out of Gerrit that will include my change which I accidentally wiped out locally?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using gerrit you should probably have access to the web interface, go there and you will see your change.

Another option if you have gitk is:

```
gitk --all `git reflog | cut -c1-7`
```

Search for your deleted branch over there and you can check it out using the hash.

Comment: yes, I ended up having to retrieve the fetch URL from the gerrit web front end

Comment: glad it worked out for you!, could you please "accept" the answer if it was helpful for you?